# bash asynchronous variable setting (dns lookup)

Tags: bash, variables, asynchronous, global

Let's say we had a loop that we want to have run as quickly as possible. Let's say something was being done to a list of hosts inside that loop; just for the sake of argument, let's say it was a redis query. Let's say that the list of hosts may change occasionally due to hosts being added/removed from a pool (not load balanced); however, the list is predictable (e.g., they all start with “foo” and end with 2 digits. So we want to run this occasionally; say, once every 15 minutes:

```
listOfHosts=$(dig +noall +ans foo{00..99}.domain | while read -r n rest; do printf '%s\n' ${n%.}; done)
```

to get the list of hosts. Let's say our loop looked something like this:

```
while :; do
    for i in $listOfHosts; do
        redis-cli -h $i llen something
    done
    (( ( $(date +%s) % 60 * 15) == 0 )) && callFunctionThatSetslistOfHosts
done
```

(now obviously there's some things missing, like testing to see if we've already run callFunctionThatSetslistOfHosts in the current minute and only running it once, and doing something with the redis output, and maybe the list of hosts should be an array, but basically this is it.)

How can we run callFunctionThatSetslistOfHosts asynchronously so that it doesn't slow down the loop. I.e., have it running in the background setting listOfHosts occasionally (e.g. once every 15 minutes), so that the next time the inner loop is run it gets a potentially different set of hosts to run the redis query on?

My major problem seems to be that in order to set listOfHosts in a loop, that loop has to be a subshell, and listOfHosts is local to that subshell, and setting it doesn't affect the global listOfHosts.

I may resort to pipes, but will have to poll the reader before generating a new list — not that that's terribly bad if I poll slowly, but I thought I'd present this as a problem.

Thanks.